# Change the width of area, in which the browser shows the title, is it possible?

Tags: jquery

Let's assume i have a `a` tag with title attribute

`<a title="some text here">`;

is it possible to change the width of area, in which the title shown?

Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

No, the `title` is browser specific implementation. You will need to roll your own title implementation using divs in order to personalize its aspect.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you may do is to add padding with white-space characters, such as

```
<a title="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;some text here&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/zzcjw/)

Not really setting the width, but that's what you get :p
Not sure about browser compatibility, but it works here on chrome.

EDIT: Actually don't have to use entities either it seems, so plain spacebar-pressing is sufficient..

Comment: Can't help you with those I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, but still you got a lot of jQuery add on to do that.
For example, i use [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on static `title` tooltip, you can implement your own tooltips.

Take a look at: [15 jQuery Plugins to Create Tooltips](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/)